# Escaping urlencoded for Twilio API | Javascript

Tags: javascript, twilio, urlencode, node-red, twilio-api

I am sending out messages to the Twilio API for Whatsapp with `['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` which works perfectly fine, apart from the fact that I can't seem to escape most special characters in the message's body.

```
Cat & Dog: http://catdog.io
```

becomes

```
Cat &amp; Dog: http:&#x2F;&#x2F;catdog.io
```

Neither encodeURIComponent nor encodeURI do the trick and in the delivered message end up as

```
Cat%20%26%20Dog%3A%20http%3A%2F%2Fcatdog.io
```

and

```
Cat%20&amp;%20Dog:%20http:&#x2F;&#x2F;catdog.io
```

respectively.

Anything I am missing / have completely wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you actually making the request here? Can you share code or your NodeRed node?

Comment: Sure! Added them to the question.

Comment: I can see you're passing JSON, but the API request expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (you are already setting the content-type header correctly for that). I wonder if, because you are putting the data through JSON that it is getting double escaped somehow. For reference, your ampersands should be encoded as `%26` and your spaces should be `%20`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are work with node.js, you can use npm querystring [click to see](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)

Comment: Thanks Marius, will try that. I'm currently on Node-Red, but will try to npm-install querystring there.
What I don't understand yet is how an escaped & is supposed to look like, for instance.
I'm passing the strings in question within a JSON object by the way, but it's not a matter of escaping JSON either.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** In the Template node of Node-Red, needed to put payload in **triple brackets**, not double, like this:

```
{ "To": "whatsapp:+4567890123", "From": "whatsapp:+1234567890", "Body":"{{{payload}}}"}
```